# 3d rotation using flash

Tags: flash

this is a post with a lot of questions so please be patient with me.
im a newbie website and flash programmer and my programming experience is mostly on c and python. however, when i saw the [3D CAR MODEL](http://www.yofla.com/flash/3d-rotate/examples.php) dynamic flash image i immediately wanted to make my own. im not sure if the link is working for you but what the image does is revolve about the x-y-z axes.

to  begin my barrage of questions (sorry):

1. in my very limited understanding regarding making flash , i believe there are several programs for doing this. **so in your opinion what is the lightest flash making program to create 3d images?**
2. my application would be like this: a separate program sends the angular position to the dynamic image to the flash image. **so is this possible with flash: data from a separate program controlling a flash image?**
3. lastly, since my intended application would run on a website, **am i legally (and is it even possible) allowed to attach the said input-dependent 3d image on a website?**

forgive me for asking too many questions. thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Welcome! It's better if you post three questions. You'll receive more attention per item. Also, try to circumvent the "subjective" side of things by evading words like "opinion", "what do you think?", etc. , as they tend to enhance the probabilities of your post being closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I doubt they used a "flash making program" to make the 3D images. I presume they're pre-rendered pictures made in some unrelated 3D modelling software.
2. Yes, it's possible. You can control a Flash object with, say, JavaScript. ...however now that you mention it it would be better to just do the whole thing in JS. No need to invoke a browser plugin for something like this.
3. Why the hell would there be a law against 3D images on the web!? As long as you have the copyright for the images (or have a license to use them), of course you can use them on the web.

Comment: thanks for replying sir. ive read your reply and all was made clear to me save this part "however now that you mention it it would be better to just do the whole thing in JS" does this mean that there is a javascript option that will allow me to create a revolving car?

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: All the Flash thing does is display one of a set of pre-rendered images depending on the current angle. That's what the loading bar at the start is for - it's loading a hundred or so images! You can do that using pretty much anything.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen hello and welcome. so javascript can do what flash does too? should i focus my attention on javascript instead of flash for my intended application?

Comment: @user: In my opinion, yes. You should always prefer HTML and JS over Flash, if in any way feasible.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen thanks for replying! as a final clarification and note: my application is exactly as you guessed it, it displays an image based on some input angle. i was worried since the model im planning on making should have the capability to display say, tilted 30 degrees with respect to the horizontal SIMULTANEOUSLY with being tilted with the z-axis (zoom in zoom out axis from my view). combinations of the said tilt can still be accomplished via java right?

Comment: @user: I'm not talking about Java, I'm talking about JavaScript. In the Flash you posted, simultaneous rotations are done by just having a separate image for each combination of rotations. Zooming can be done by just resizing the image.

Comment: As Matti says, the examples you linked to simply loads and shows a series of images, and that can be implemented in JavaScript. If you want to work with 3D that is based on calculations and 3D models instead of pre-rendered images, you could use Flash and a library like http://away3d.com. WebGL will make such 3D stuff possible in browsers without plugins, but support for it is not yet implemented in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

So, It will depend what you desire to do with flash:

1. You can use softwares like Poser that exports flash films. Maya and 3DS Max should be used to. But you are trying to expor a kind of 3d model that will be rendered according commands on flash, like rotate, zoom in/out, etc. Probably you'll be able to do it with the right tools and codes.
2. You can control Flash with many other development tools. I've used even Delphi to do it. Its worth to spend a good time reading the ActionScript blueprints... http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/
3. Ok, let's clarify one thing: you'll put the art on a web page, not the software. The art is yours, unless another person created it. You don't need to be concerned about legall issues while using your own work. It's different if you are going to use a 3rd part plugin, then, you should be using "their" work.